Unity. Behavior Tree
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли популярные бесплатные инструменты для Unity, чтобы работать с Behavior Tree? К сожалению, в магазине ассетов я нашёл только платный ассет, который подходит для разработки. Есть бесплатные, но они давно заброшены и судя по отзывам - очень нестабильные. Я бы и рад оплатить, но сейчас это сделать очень сложно.
Да, я знаю, что необязательно иметь редактор для BT и можно реализовать эту концепцию вручную, но всё же намного удобнее, когда дерево визуализировано.

Есть пакет от самих Unity: com.unity.behavior. Написано, что можно использовать без подписки Muse: "It's free to use Unity Behavior, but you need a Muse subscription to access the generative artificial intelligence (AI) features of the tool." Вероятно, доступен только в Unity 6.

Ознакомлюсь, спасибо большое
